# Manager not load balancing in Docker

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, docker-swarm

When I access the manager node in MANAGERIP, it doesn't load balance to it's workers, but if I access WORKERIP, they will load balance between themselves and leave manager out.

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        image: -
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: "0.5"
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "8080:80"
        networks:
          - webnet
        volumes:
          - /home/{{ ansible_user }}/.env:/home/opus/.env
          - /home/{{ ansible_user }}/database.php:/home/opus/config/database.php
    networks:
      webnet:
```

It's a configuration problem? All the nodes are Reachable by manager and all of them are running the container.

Comment: Do you have any firewall between the nodes or on any of the nodes (including iptables)? Are you able to connect to containers running on different nodes using the overlay network?

Comment: I opened all ports on the Google Platform firewall, from 0 to 65535. As the worker nodes do load balance between themselves I think it's not a firewall problem, but I will try to connect to worker nodes from the manager. I will leave the feedback soon.
Thanks

Comment: With docker network inspect opus_webnet I can see all the workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I could not advertise the external ip to the swarm, so the correct syntax is:

```
docker swarm init
    --advertise-addr=**GoogleCloud Machine Internal IP(10.*.*.*)**
```

The same thing goes for the docker join, the workers should use the manager internal IP.

Comment: That would suggest you had a firewall somewhere, blocking the overlay networking traffic to the public ip's.